# Scrollview not working inside linearlayout

Tags: android, listview

I want to use scrollview inside linearlayout and want to scroll particular this layout but it is not working.this is my code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:scrollbars="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_custom_action_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_client_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp15"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_layout_white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/img_user_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_client_name"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp50"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_client_scheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                android:dividerHeight="0sp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"></ListView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp300"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_summary_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp25"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dp12" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp2"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp30"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="Total Amount Invested"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_total_invst_amt"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp40"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp5"

                              android:background="@drawable/corner_border"
                                android:gravity="center|right"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text="9,857.51"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp5"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp30"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="Total Current Amount"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_total_Curr_val"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp40"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp5"

                              android:background="@drawable/corner_border"
                                android:gravity="center|right"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text="9,857.51"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp2"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp3"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="5">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="right|center"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text="Total Gain/Loss ST"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_total_gl_St"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="center|right"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp2"
                                android:background="@color/colorWhite" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="right|center"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text="Total Gain/Loss LT"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_total_gl_lt"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="center|right"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp2"
                                android:background="@color/colorWhite" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="right|center"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text="Total Dividend Reinvest"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_total_div_amt"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="center|right"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp2"
                                android:background="@color/colorWhite" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="right|center"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text="Total Ret ABS"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_ret_abs"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="center|right"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp2"
                                android:background="@color/colorWhite" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="right|center"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text="Total Weg. CAGR"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_weg_cagr"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="center|right"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

How I modify this code to scroll layout? I want to scroll particular layout inside the main linear layout.is it fine? guide me over this.is this code is ok?
How I use scroll view inside the linear layout.

Comment: `it is not working` is not the best description of a problem. Please try to be more specific to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use NestedScrollView inside another scrolling view

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: i set fillviewport= true to get whole content of listview still scrolling is not working in nestedscrollview

Comment: use scrollview at the root of layout and in between of layout use NestedScroolview

Comment: used scrollview as root layout still unable to scroll layout

Comment: listview display only one item and scrolling not occur

Comment: share your listview layout xml

Answer (score 0):

You can put your nested scroll view in parent.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the layout which you want to make scrollable with ScrollView and set orientation to vertical or vertical.In  your code,remove nested scroll view and try once